# 'Use of unresolved identifier resnet50()' after putting in resnet50() into the project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

[image]

As shown in the picture I have the model in my project and the model is working as a class but it is still unresolved identifier

Comment: Welcome to SO. Never post code as image. It makes it harder for someone to re-produce it in order to help you. Edit your question and add your code as part of the question. But before doing that, look at [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set target membership for the model to get it work.